# SAS Vector plot: disappearance of vector lines

Tags: sas

I have been trying to make a Vector plot in SAS using the SAShelp library 'Class'. The goal is to make a vector plot with the origins of the vectors in the respective means of the x and y variables. I used the following code:

> ```
> DATA class2;
> SET Sashelp.class;
> x = mean(height);
> y=mean(weight);
> run;
> PROC SGPLOT DATA = class2;
> VECTOR X = height Y = weight / XORIGIN = x YORIGIN = y;
> run;
> ```

I thus first created two new variables, containing the means of the X and Y variable. Then I wanted to place the origin of the vectors in these origins, but when I do this, the vectors disappear in my plot and all I get is a plot with some dots.

Any suggestions on how to solve this, and especially, how this disappearance of the vectors has been caused?

Thank you in advance,
Koen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean() function does not work across the entire data set.  Data Steps deal with a single record at a time (think of it as SAS writing an outer loop for processing for you.

You can use SQL to get the means and then add them to the data set.  I also added data labels for you.

```
proc sql noprint;
select mean(height), mean(weight)
    into :mh, :mw
    from class2;
quit;

DATA class2;
SET Sashelp.class;
x = &mh;
y= &mw;
run;

PROC SGPLOT DATA = class2;
VECTOR X = height Y = weight / XORIGIN = x YORIGIN = y datalabel=name;
run;
```

Produces this:
[image]